# Why recursive function is not memoized

Tags: clojure

Hello I can't wrap my head around this problem:

```
(defn integrate
  "Finding the definite integral from 0 to stop"
  ([f dx]
   (let [itg (memoize
              (fn [itg stop n]
                (if (<= n 0)
                  0
                  (+ (let [b (* n dx) a (- b dx)]
                       (println "[DEBUG] stop = " stop " and n =" n) 
                       (* (- b a) (/ (+ (f a) (f b)) 2))
                      )
                     (itg itg stop (dec n))))))
         itg (partial itg itg)]
     (fn [x] (itg x (quot x dx))))))

(time ((integrate (fn [x] (* x x)) 0.1) 5))
(time ((integrate (fn [x] (* x x)) 0.1) 5))
```

I expect that the 2nd time I call this function, it should hit the memoized result, but it just recalculates the whole integral the second time and prints the DEBUG messages all over again.

Why this happens? How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems.  1) Each call to `integrate` creates a fresh memoized function, so a second call to `integrate` won't reuse any results computed by the first call. 2) One of the parameters to the memoized function is itself a function. It is not true that `(= (fn []) (fn []))`, so the memo might not match as often as you hope.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good write-up on this issue here: https://quanttype.net/posts/2020-09-20-local-memoized-recursive-functions.html